# What permission is required to access the ListEdgeNodes operation in the Azure REST API?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cdn

I am trying to use the [Azure SDK for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/?view=azure-dotnet) to get the list of IP addresses for CDN edge nodes. I created a service principal using the following Azure CLI command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth
```

My code looks like this:

```
var creds = SdkContext
    .AzureCredentialsFactory
    .FromServicePrincipal(
        "[client-id]", 
        "[client-secret]", 
        "[tenant-id]", 
        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            
var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .Authenticate(creds)
    .WithDefaultSubscription();
        
var edgeNodes = azure.CdnProfiles.ListEdgeNodes();

// ... do other things
```

When I call this method, I get an `ErrorResponseException` with a message of `Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'`. I can call all the other methods on the `CdnProfiles` object without any issue.

Any ideas on what permission I need to grant my service principal in order to access this endpoint?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I am thinking this may be a bug. The following code works fine, using the same service principal:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var clientId = "[client-id]";
    var clientSecret = "[client-secret]";
    var tenantId = "[tenant-id]";
    var tenantDomainName = "[tenant-domain-name]";
    var subscriptionId = "[subscription-id]";
    var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/{tenantDomainName}";

    var authResult = await GetAccessTokenAsync(clientId, clientSecret, authority);

    var cdn = new CdnManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(authResult.AccessToken))
        { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

    var edgeNodes = await cdn.EdgeNodes.ListAsync();
}

private static Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAccessTokenAsync(string clientId, string clientSecret, string authority)
{
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    return authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", credential);
}
```

Comment: Could you check in your portal what permissions are set. It looks you still don't have access to them.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-app-dev-net

Comment: @maxspan Thank you for the suggestion. The service principal I'm using has the `Contributor` role on the subscription. I tried explicitly adding `CDN Profile Contributor` and `CDN Endpoint Contributor` but am getting the same exception. It's odd because it seems listing the edge nodes could just be a public endpoint because it isn't tied to any particular CDN profile.

Comment: So actually what you want to do is to use this api?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/EdgeNodes/List

Comment: @JoyWang That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around it for now by upgrading `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn` to `5.0.0-preview` and using the `CdnManagementClient`.

```
var creds = SdkContext
    .AzureCredentialsFactory
    .FromServicePrincipal(
        "[client-id]", 
        "[client-secret]", 
        "[tenant-id]", 
        AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
    
var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.CdnManagementClient(creds);

var edgeNodes = client.EdgeNodes.List();

// ... do other things
```

This code works as expected. I still believe this is a bug, so I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/13714) if anyone runs into this in the future.

EDIT:

This did end up being a bug. [A fix was merged](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/pull/1117) so it should work as expected in future releases of the library.